Ubuntu Studio 24.10: "Some required theme snaps are missing" error message persists on every login
On login and reboot, a popup appears with the message "Some required theme snaps are missing. Would you like to install them now?" Pressing "yes" always results in a "Failed" message and the popup appears on every subsequent login. From searching forums, this appears to be related the installed Orchis theme (which I do not use), and uninstalling and reinstalling the theme might resolve the issue. However, it appears as though Orchis cannot be uninstalled in Ubuntu Studio. Is there another workaround?  (Ubuntu 24.10, KDE Plasma Version 6.1.5.)

This doesn't seem right since we make sure the Orchis gtk theme is pre-seeded before you even install. Try opening a terminal and try sudo snap install gtk-theme-orchis.
